# Relational database with Kafka-like durability/caching implementation

Tags: database-design, replication, query-performance, kafka

When reading about Kafka I found it really interesting how they are providing durability, especially in comparison to databases:

- Kafka - never writes synchronously to disk, provides durability by replicating to other servers (and getting their confirmation); the added benefit is that it can reuses filesystem cache instead of rolling out your own
- relational database - flush log to disk to guarantee durability.

From what I was reading the Kafka approach results in a better performance so I was wondering if there is anything in particular that makes this approach infeasible for relational database? Or maybe some of the "NewSQL" guys are doing it and I'm just unaware?

Sources about Kafka mechanisms I'm talking about:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#persistence
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication

Comment: "never writes synchronously to disk, **provides durability by replicating to other servers (and getting their confirmation)**" -- this is literally the definition of writing synchronously to disk, with the added "benefit" of network latency, because the disk is elsewhere.

Comment: @mustaccio That would be the case but the other servers are doing the same. They write it to file, but without flushing, which means the ack can be sent back as soon as data is written into the page cache

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but it's not going to be the thing that solves your performance problems. All these different systems try to get crafty to solve the performance problems of the 0.01% of use cases, but almost certainly any actual performance problems one faces regularly in their database system (form a software perspective) is due to either poorly architected database (inclusive of poorly designed schema, bad or no indexing, or poorly designed systems interacting with the database, etc) or poorly written queries, or needed routine database maintenance (e.g. index and/or query tuning).

Comment: And to mustaccio's point, if it waits for confirmation while the data is being written on disk elsewhere, then it's waiting on a disk latency that's no different than if it wrote to its own local disk, except the additional latency of sending the data across the network, as pointed out. So it's possible it could even be slower in some cases due to this. If the use of *caching* is what interests you, modern RDMBS like SQL Server essentially cache *hot* data in Memory. Add the appropriate amount of Memory to your server, and boom, you have caching.

Comment: @J.D. I take your point about bottlenecks being elsewhere, but isn't synchronous write to disk on commit a performance hit in workloads when you have a lot of transactions?

Comment: @J.D. One clarification - synchronous write is not required, either on the master or on the replicas. Durability is achieved by replicating data to multiple nodes, but it's enough for those nodes to have data in memory. Flushing to disk is asynchronous and happens at their own convenience.
If such a server dies, the data that was in memory is lost - but other replicas still have it

Comment: @KrysztofNaware If you're saying the main server marks a transaction as hardened once it gets confirmation from the other servers that the data is only in Memory on the other servers, then to your point, what happens if all replicas die while it's still in Memory? Then the data is permanently lost, and it wasn't truly hardened. So I think you might be misunderstanding how it works a little. I don't personally know much about Kafka, but from a general sense of how **Durability** works, I would assume Kafka is waiting for confirmation that at least 1 node hardened the transaction to **Disk**.

Comment: "but other replicas still have it" -- unless they also die, along with the rest of the equipment in that data centre.

Comment: What you're saying is all very true - if all replicas die then (some) of the data is lost. But is disk that much more "hardened"? Disks are known to fail. Even with RAID you could have could have multiple disks go down due to surge or domino effect during recovery.
In the face of datacenter-wide disaster I can see how disks are superior. Replicating to other datacenters would introduce a huge latency. But with the backup power my impression was that such an event would be relatively rare?

Comment: Is seems to me that durability is never absolute. And major vendors offers configuration options that allow to trade durability for performance.
Even if system inspired by Kafka cannot compete with durability of fully synchronous drives in RAID e.g. 10, it's surely more durable than a master or master-slave system but with lowered durability setting?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on false premises and misunderstanding, and also very broad.

Comment: @mustaccio If that's what the rules are. I already learned a lot, but I don't mind learning more. It'd be useful for me if you wrote more about my false assumptions and the things that I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine statements in your question in some detail.

You say:

> Kafka - never writes synchronously to disk, provides durability by replicating to other servers (and getting their confirmation); the added benefit is that it can reuses filesystem cache instead of rolling out your own

That is true inasmuch we understand "durability" as it is understood by the Kafka developers. They say in [their documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design):

> each partition in Kafka has a single leader and zero or more followers[...] All reads and writes go to the leader of the partition[...]

and

> All data is immediately written to a persistent log on the filesystem without necessarily flushing to disk. In effect this just means that it is transferred into the kernel's pagecache.

Dirty pages will be written out by the flusher threads after a configurable interval that on Linux defaults to, I believe, 5 seconds, during which time Kafka thinks the data are durable while in fact they are not at all.

Oh wait, replication!

> We generally feel that the guarantees provided by replication are stronger than sync to local disk

Fair enough. How does that work?

> Followers consume messages from the leader just as a normal Kafka consumer would and apply them to their own log[...] a follower [...] must replicate the writes happening on the leader and not fall "too far" behind.

Followers will make their logs "durable" subject to the same pagecache flush logic. And what is "not too far behind"? It's controlled by the setting `replica.socket.timeout.ms`, which defaults to 30 seconds<sup>1</sup>. In other words, data on followers may not be persisted to disk for up to 35 seconds after it was written (to the pagecache) on the leader.

All this means that in the worst failure scenario you might lose anywhere between 5 and 35 seconds' worth of data.

And it can be just fine for Kafka, which is a *messaging system*. After all, the source can always resend the data it has, can't it<sup>2</sup>?

A database, on the other hand, is by definition is a system of record; a "durability guarantee" of the sort "meh, you might lose about 30 seconds of transactions, so what!" won't buy you much credibility.

So, Kafka developers "feel" that the probability of disk failure is higher than the probability of network or process failure (however, see footnote 1 for some incongruity). They don't support their statement by any data, but my experience tells me quite the opposite is true, especially when you fashionably run your workloads "in the cloud" or on a container platform.

---

You also say:

> relational database - flush log to disk to guarantee durability

Most of them do, for the reason indicated above: *somebody* has to remember the data in order to allow you to resend them when Kafka loses some. Typical transaction log buffer flush latency on modern hardware is in the range of 2-4 ms, so performance penalty is very small and at most you lose a single transaction. That is certainly more durable.

Some databases, e.g. [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_timeout), allow you to control when the log buffer is flushed, which offers you essentially the same trade-off as Kafka.

Databases also offer replication capabilities, but they are there to improve *availability*, not durability of data.

---

1 - It used to be 10 seconds but was increased "for improved resiliency in typical network environments".
2 - Often it can not.

Comment: Thanks! I want to mention some points which are not explicitly in you answer to make sure you factored them in.
For me the critical properties for durability is acks = 1 which requires at least min.insync.replicas to acknowledge the data before the producer will be informed that the data has been durably stored. If it doesn't get those acks, the leader won't tell consumers that data is durable so the customer need to be ready to redo the operation/resend the data.

Comment: This means loss of data happens if *all* those nodes fail at OS level or lower, not just the process (as if something is in page cache, it will be written even if the process crashes).

Comment: Also very useful point about MySQL - I was looking at Postgres and couldn't find a mechanism that would allow you to enable synchronous replication without mandating a synchronous commit. It all seems to be controlled by synchronous_commit configuration

In case of MySQL I believe we would also need the semi-synchronous replication enabled:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-semisync.html

Comment: correction: in the first comment *consumer* was supposed to be *producer*