# Why do database need logging?

Tags: write-ahead-logging

Most databases today have WAL (undo, redo), but why do databases need them?

Take a simple case of RocksDB deployment. I would imagine a storage/database cluster will have a certain redundancy scheme (erasure coding or replication) for fault tolerance, but I don't see why application level also needs fault tolerance.
For example, when one server temporarily (or permanently) fails, I would think the recovery will use the other servers' data because there will be new data written during the time when the server fails and you cannot just rely on the logging to recover the server. Do I have a misunderstanding somewhere?

Not sure this is the right place for this question, if not, happy to ask at a different place. Thank you!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299805/relational-database-with-kafka-like-durability-caching-implementation)

Comment: Thank you! @mustaccio This is not exactly a duplicate, I would like to know what is done in reality, is the log actually useful in production. The answer you pointed to is very interesting and helpful. But I am not convinced, the answer assumes the worst case scenario that all replicas are dead, but we can also assume all disks are dead (and logging cannot be used) :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if a database has a redundancy feature such as the ones you mentioned, that doesn't mean the developer / DBA who setup the database server, actually enabled and configured those features. While many modern database systems support those kinds of features, generally it requires an additional server, database instance, and / or separate storage device(s). The database has no knowledge of what your intentions are, and therefore logging **is** its way of natively implementing a redundancy scheme of sorts.

Additionally, logging is meant to happen *local* to the database instance that it's for, to help ensure Consistency and Durability (think [ACID principles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)). The redundancy features you mentioned are typically not local, which open them up to an additional set of issues that can occur across the network, while trying to keep the data synchronized in two different places, depending on when the primary database server goes down. Depending on how the redundancy was implemented, you could run into unwanted transactions being committed or rolled back when they shouldn't have been.

Comment: Just a small point, logging mainly covers the Durability bit of ACID not Consistency (which is more to do with constraints). Writing to a local log is going to be much faster than writing to another database over the network (although you will typically do both in an enterprise in case of disasters).

Comment: @AndrewSayer Thanks, yea my morning brain couldn't recall if I really wanted to mention Consistency or Durability regarding ACID principles in reference to logging. Thinking about it now, I believe both are equally relevant here though, since the logging system will know when it can roll a transaction forward or back completely, to maintain Consistency, during a failure. But right, the importance of logging is respective of Durability as well, since it ensures the hardening of the transaction to durable storage.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! @J.D. and @Andrew! Re: "since the logging system will know when it can roll a transaction forward or back completely, to maintain Consistency, during a failure" Will the log (or data) on the failed server used during recovery? (assuming a enterprise cluster with redundancy)

Comment: @1a1a11a That's a bit complicated question and very dependent on the specific database system and redundancy feature you're talking about. I wouldn't know how RocksDB works, but for Microsoft SQL Server as an example, if a cluster was setup with the AlwaysOn Availability Groups feature, and the secondary replica was a synchronous replica, then the logs at the primary replica are only hardened once they are replicated and hardened on the secondary replica. That way, if the primary goes down, the secondary's log is already in sync with the primary's. This helps *reduce* the chance of data loss.